# Update the dynamic amount of records based on another field

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I want to update records in a table. 
These records I want to update should be in order (first by pkey asc).
Next the qty I want to update will be stored in another field.

**`update` table**

```
pkey description status tray
---- ----------- ------ ----
1    widget      0      0
2    widget      1      0
3    widget      1      0
4    widget      1      0
5    widget      2      0
6    widget      2      0
```

**`widget` table**

```
desc   QtyPerCase
------ ----------
widget 2
```

For this example I want to update the first (`qtypercase`) to tray XX order by `pkey` asc.
There will be different widgets and `qtypercase` so I need it to be dynamic.

**Expected result:**

```
pkey description status tray
---- ----------- ------ ----
1    widget      0      0
2    widget      1      99
3    widget      1      99
4    widget      1      0
5    widget      2      0
6    widget      2      0
```

I hope I asked this well. Thanks guys in advance for the help.

Comment: How your end result should look alike?

Comment: Sybase is the DB. I want to update tray to 99 so end result would be pkey description status tray
---- ----------- ------ ----
1    widget      0      0
2    widget      1      99
3    widget      1      99
4    widget      1      0
5    widget      2      0
6    widget      2      0

Comment: Sybase is the DB. I want to update the  tray column to 99 so end result would be pkey records of 2 and 3 would have tray column to 99.

Comment: I didnt explain this very well. Maybe a better way to explain it is to say I want to update a qty of records and that qty of record to update is in another table. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: @PSikorski I don't understand why "1 widget 0 0" didn't get an upate? Do you specify the status too?
In my opinion the easiest way to solve this, is to run a cursor over #widget and using a while condition inside of it (`while @c1_ QtyPerCase > 0`). Then update the row with the lowest `pkey` and not having `tray`= 99.